# Dynamics 2011 Intersect / Junction entity

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have 3 entities.

`PortalRole`, `Person` and `PersonPortalRole`

`PersonPortalRole` is a intersection entity to deal with my [Many-Many relationship.](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/richardknudson/archive/2011/05/08/many-to-many-relationships-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)

I am using JavaScript through a HTML web resource to allow the creation and removal of this entity. I can create new entities by using the REST service fairly easily but I can't find a way of deleting a intersect record (two lookup fields) using the `PersonId` and `PortalRoleId`.

Has anyone had any exposure to either deleting a record through REST using the two foreign keys values from a lookup? I was trying to get the object first using a filter but can't seemt o filter using the lookup primary keys.

Was trying something like below which returns 15 entries to then filter the results to get the primary key, and then delete using that key but not sure on the way to do this.

> SERVER/INSTANCE/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/personportalrolesSet?$expand=Person,PortalRole

Comment: Are you just trying to delete the record in the PersonPortalRole table (with columns PersonPortalRoleID, PortalRoleID, and PersonID) that contains the linkage between the PortalRole and the Person?

Comment: yes basically. But can't seem to find a way of deleting without having to do another round trip to get the entity first

Answer (score 0):

Based on that URI, you are interacting with an OData service.  OData uses Atom feeds for returning lists of stuff so you will likely find within each `<entry>` element a `<id>` element that contains the URL of the resource.  If you issue a HTTP DELETE to that URL then your resource will be deleted.

See docs here http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#DeletingEntries

Comment: I've explored that link before and can work out how to delete something based on its primary key but not on lookup.PK

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the REST endpoint, but there's no way I know of to end a many-to-many relationship except through sending a `Disassociate` request (or if you have access to the SQL box, direct insertion/deletion in that table).  MS has some [sample code available that shows how to do this using the REST Endpoint.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372956.aspx#BKMK_JScriptRESTAssociateDisassociateJS)